# injecting arguments versus returning data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand when to inject something like the response into a function, versus calling a function and returning something from it. In Node.js that is.

Do any functions in Node.js return data? Or is it all about injecting arguments and using callbacks?

```
var sendHTMLToBrowser = require("../myCode/andrewsHelpers").sendHTMLToBrowser;
//var execExternalCommand = require("./childProcesses").execExternalCommand;
// import the exec function defined on the child_process module
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function start(response, request) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called");

    var body = '<!doctype html>'+
        '<html lang="en">'+
        '<head>'+
        '<meta charset=UTF-8" />'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
        '<p>Hello Andrew :)</p>'+
        '</body>'+
        '</html>';

    sendHTMLToBrowser(response, body);
}

function linecount(response, request) {
    console.log("Request handler 'linecount' was called.");

    // launch the command "cat *.js | wc -l"
    exec('cat *.js | wc -l', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        // the command exited or the launching failed
        if (err) {
            // we had an error launching the process
            console.log('child process exited with error code', err.code);
            return;
        }
        sendHTMLToBrowser(response, stdout.toString());
    });
}

function executeCommand(command) {

    return result;
}

exports.start = start;
exports.linecount = linecount;
```

So I've hardcoded in some code to display the linecount in the browser. What if I wanted to make a more generic function, that took a command as a string and returned the output? Would I again inject response into this function or could I return the result?

Is it a question as to whether a command will potentially become a block? e.g. doing some basic string manipulation could probably be implemented as a function that returns a value?

thanks.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a Templating Engine.

Here's a list of node.js supported ones: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

Comment: Any function that involves I/O, would require a callback. In your question you are executing an external program so yes it will require a callback.

Comment: The subject of your question is a fundamental paradigm of node.js and you will be better served reading tutorials and trying examples whereas stackoverflow is better for specific problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a callback instead of a return value if your function:

- does any asynchronous I/O (filesystem, network, child process, etc)
- uses process.nextTick
- uses setTimeout
- uses setInterval

Any of those things will cause your function to span more than a single event loop "tick" thus requiring a callback.

If all you do is regular in-memory javascript computation, you can just return a value.

And if you want to have both a return value and do IO, you can return a promise.